# sorting elements out of the list

Tags: python

I need to step some elements from a list (in this case n)
I has also another list ( o list)

```
n=['A','B','C','D','E']
o=['A','B','C','D','E','AS','sd','Z','R']
n.sort()
```

Now if I use this code:

```
for o in sorted(n):
```

The code is run for `'A','B','C','D','E'`.

I need to run the for code but just only `'AS','sd','Z','R'` items.

Something like : run the code for items from o list without items from n list

Comment: be aware that iterating `for o in sorted(n)` will overwrite the content of the list `o`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works only if `o` has no duplicates:

```
n = ['A','B','C','D','E']
o = ['A','B','C','D','E','AS','sd','Z','R']
a = sorted(set(o) - set(n))

# a == ['AS', 'R', 'Z', 'sd']
```

otherwise use this:

```
n = ['A','B','C','D','E']
o = ['A','B','C','D','E','AS','sd','Z','R', 'AS']
s = set(n)
a = sorted(elem for elem in o if elem not in s)

# a == ['AS', 'AS', 'R', 'Z', 'sd']
```

Comment: Be aware that your if condition creates a new `set` on each iteration.

Comment: better to calculate `set(n)` outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Python) for the filtering and sorted() for the sorting:

```
for item in sorted(element for element in n if element not in o):
  print item
```

If `n` tends to be large, it would be faster to create a set first:

```
forbidden = set(o)
for item in sorted(element for element in n if element not in forbidden):
  print item
```

**EDIT:** added a set and using a generator expression instead as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Only down side of this is performance -- iterating through o (rather than creating a set of it first and doing a lookup against the set) isn't so fast.

Comment: you can leave out the `[]`. `sorted` works fine with a generator expression

Answer (score 0):

Set has such operations.

```
n=['A','B','C','D','E']
o=['A','B','C','D','E','AS','sd','Z','R']

for ab in set(o).difference(set(n)):
    print ab
```

Comment: Add a `sorted()` invocation and this would be perfect.

Comment: It wouldn't be perfect because `sets` dont keep duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = ['A','B','C','D','E']
o = ['A','B','C','D','E','AS','sd','Z','R']
result = sorted(set(o) - set(n))
```

Comment: @gnibbler sets are ordered, but it's not the order of inclusion.

Comment: @moooeeeep, I raise you a link http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset "A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects. "

Comment: @gnibbler apparantly it's the order of the hashes, isn't it?

Comment: @gnibbler of course you are right, obviously I had a misconception about the details of a hashmap. Must have confused it somehow with C++' `std::set` which is implemented as a binary search tree.

Comment: @gnibbler : Correct and agreed